# Use forward slash in variable

Tags: bash, slash

I wrote a script to ease the syncing and building of Android source. I tried adding a function to cherrypick patches, but I can't get it to work properly. I know it's because of the forward slashes, but I don't know how to protect/escape them.

Part of the code is:

```
   echo "Copy/paste the project folder, i.e. 'frameworks/base'"
   read folder
   echo ""
   echo "Now paste the cherry-pick git link, i.e. 'git fetch <someproject> refs/changes/... && git cherry-pick FETCH_HEAD'"
   read cherry
   echo ""
   Begin
   clear
   echo ""
   export IFS="&&"
   for x in $cherry
   do
        cd ${CM}/${folder}
    CHERRY=$(trim "$x")
    $CHERRY
   done
```

Let's say that the 'cherry' variable is:

```
git fetch http://r.cyanogenmod.com/CyanogenMod/android_frameworks_base refs/changes/68/22968/2 && git cherry-pick FETCH_HEAD
```

I would get this error:

```
/home/tristan202/bin/build_cm.sh: line 159: git fetch http://r.cyanogenmod.com/CyanogenMod/android_frameworks_base refs/changes/91/23491/2: No such file or directory
/home/tristan202/bin/build_cm.sh: line 159: git cherry-pick FETCH_HEAD: command not found
```

I cannot figure out why it fails.

The 'trim' function it calls is a function that trims leading and trailing spaces. If I do echo "$CHERRY" within the for loop, the commands are printed correctly, but it still fails.

Answer (score 3):

I will give your another example:

```
cmd='echo hello && echo world'
$cmd
```

The result is:

```
hello && echo world
```

---

bash parses the command `$cmd` as [`Simple Commands`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Simple-Commands) not [`Lists of Commands`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Lists).
After [`Parameter Expansion`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion), `&&` is passed as argument to `echo`(1st word after [`Word Splitting`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Word-Splitting)).

---

The solution is pulling `&&` out:

```
cmd1='echo hello'
cmd2='echo world'
$cmd1 && $cmd2
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you put `&&` in a variable it ceases to be interpreted as separating two commands:

```
$ A="echo a && echo b"
$ echo $A
echo a && echo b
$ echo c && ${A}
c
a && echo b
```

So you need to avoid putting `&&` into a variable.

git was even telling you that the `&&` was the problem in its error message.

Comment: So what I need to do is write a couple lines of code that splits up the git command from the gerrit, so that it splits it at the &&. Would that be sufficient?